# Easiest way to do "git grep" for multiple strings?

Tags: git

I often need to search for lines containing multiple strings/patterns in a git project e.g.

```
git grep -i -e str1 --and -e str2 --and -e str3 -- *strings*txt
```

This gets tedious very quickly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe use TextExpander?

Comment: That's a good idea :)

Answer (score 4):

I find it easiest to use extended regular expressions `-E` and `|` (or).

```
git grep -E 'str1|str2|str3' -- *strings*txt
```

Comment: This is slick, Rick!

Answer (score 4):

A git and grep combined solution:

```
git grep --files-with-matches "str1"  | xargs grep "str2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what operating system you're using, but if it's linux-like, you can write a "wrapper" script.  Create a shell script named something like `git-grep1` and put it in a directory that's in your $PATH, so git can find it.  Then you can type `git grep1 param1 param2...` as if your script were a built-in git command.

Here's a quick example to get you started:

```sh
# Example use:  find C source files that contain "pattern" or "pat*rn"
# $ git grep1 '*.c' pattern 'pat*rn' 

# Ensure we have at least 2 params: a file name and a pattern.
[ -n "$2" ] || { echo "usage: $0 FILE_SPEC PATTERN..." >&2; exit 1; }

file_spec="$1"  # First argument is the file spec.
shift
pattern="-e $1"  # Next argument is the first pattern.
shift

# Append all remaining patterns, separating them with '--and'.
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  pattern="$pattern --and -e $1"
  shift
done

# Find the patterns in the files.
git grep -i "$pattern" -- "$file_spec"
```

You'll probably need to experiment with this, for instance, perhaps by enclosing the `$file_spec` and each pattern in single-quotes to prevent expansion by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the relative order of the strings, then you can do a

```
git grep str1.*str2.*str3 -- *strings*txt
```